# No change in array value passed by reference

Tags: c++

The below program is to reverse an array. I've passed the address of the first element of the array and it's size (size -1) to my reverse function. The elements get reversed in the function but, when I print the original in `main()` then the array's elements are not changed except for the last two elements.

It would be helpful if you explain what's happening behind my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int reverse(int *arr,int i) {
    if (*arr == NULL) {
        return *(arr-1);
    }
    --i;
    * (arr+i) = reverse((++arr),i);
    cout <<"  ar["<<i<<"]: "<<arr[i] << '\n';
    return  *(arr - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 ,NULL};
    int arr1[] = { 2,3,4 };
    reverse(&arr[0],5);
    for (int i : arr) {
        cout << " " <<i;
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

The first five lines of the output represent the recursion output while the last line represents the array's elements in `main()`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222541/discussion-on-question-by-allan-no-change-in-array-value-passed-by-reference).

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers

Answer (score 2):

Your recursion scheme is broken.
I added some tracing to your function and logged every assignment relative to the base address of the array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* reverse(int *arr, int* base, int i) {
    if (*arr == NULL) {
        return arr-1;
    }
    --i;
    int* from_recursion = reverse((arr+1),base, i);
    cout << "Storing " << from_recursion - base << " at " << arr + i - base << std::endl;
    * (arr+i) = *from_recursion;
    
    return  arr - 1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 ,NULL};
    int arr1[] = { 2,3,4 };
    reverse(&arr[0],&arr[0], 5);
    for (int i : arr) {
        cout << " " <<i;
    }
}
```

Which prints the following:

```
Storing 4 at 4
Storing 3 at 4
Storing 2 at 4
Storing 1 at 4
Storing 0 at 4
```

I'm not sure how to fix it, but here is a more conventional means of recursively reversing an array:

```
void reverse(int* arr, int i, int j) {
    if (j <= i)
        return;

    std::swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    reverse(arr, i+1, j-1);
}
```

Call it as `reverse(arr, 0, 4);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm really curious why my code or my logic doesn't work.

Comment: Your logic doesn't work because `arr+i`remains constant: you *increment* arr with every recursive call but *decrement* i. I'm still not sure what you intended to return, but it is very confusing.

Comment: upvoted, But won't recommend using recursion for this trivial task

Comment: @AryanParekh OP has not stated it, but this is obviously "recursively reverse an array"-style homework or out of curiosity.

Comment: @Botje I've used ++arr during recursive call

Comment: @Botje But still the output is same

Comment: So `reverse(arr++, i)` ? That is even more wrong. Honestly, I don't think your recursion scheme can ever work.

Comment: @Botje I'm sorry to keep asking But why?

Comment: @Botje Just curious what's happenning behind

Comment: Every step of the recursive process should swap two elements on different sides of the middle. The approach I posted above does this by keeping pointers to both sides and moving them towards the middle. Your approach walks the array left to right, and every recursive step simply returns its value, used to store on the far side . The "different sides of the middle" is thus completely missing in your approach.

Comment: @ALLAN check out my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion is a bad idea for this, also due to the design of your code, it is quite error-prone. You can avoid these errors in the first place by simply using a better design.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T,std::size_t N>
void rev_arr(T (&arr)[N])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = N-1;
    while (i < j)
    {
        std::swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    rev_arr<int,size>(arr);

    for(auto const i:arr) std::cout << i << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can reverse any type of array using the function.